# Android flush DNS cache under a Application

Tags: android, android-networking

I'm doing something for connection qualities, So I need to flush DNS cache every time I made A . Request (Not System cache since It may cause other issues), And I looked up I didn't find a way doing this,

So Is there any mechanism I could doing this?

Comment: Android does not have DNS caching itself on an OS level. It's the browsers that do the DNS caching. Are you trying to flush browser DNS cache?

Comment: DNS clearing matters only if your DNS changes quickly, so do oyu control your DNS server as well? can you use the IP in your requests instead? Can you clarify why you need this or what "something for connection qualities"? There may be a better approach.

Comment: @Madushan What I want is doing a [http trace](https://blog.golang.org/http-tracing), It does not matter about the device, Instead, I want to get this data for guessing other people's connection qualities, Simplify Just like get ping data in different countries :)

Comment: I see. I'm not really familiar with it. But why does this require DNS cache clearing? Are you trying to force a DNS lookup to measure the latency? if this is the case, you can either 1 host your own DNS server and make requests to a domain there which sets TTL very short. Or 2 make a request to a domain that you know not to exist. i.e doesntexist.domainyoucontrol.com. The request will fail, but you will get DNS timing?

Comment: @Madushan Yes, the latency of DNS lookup is an important part of System Requirement(I just need to port it from Linux to Android). And since real-world DNS server is kind of complicated(mainly considering it's cache strategies and upper nodes), So I don't think simply get the not exist domain can not reflect the real connection data :)

Answer (score 2):

Since the goal is to measure latency .etc. to a real DNS request, you have a few options.

Unfortunately I don't think you can force the device to clear DNS cache as a regular app on Android. My reasoning is that this can result in a denial of service to other apps if you keep doing this. I haven't seen any permission in android that allows this, unless you have a rooted device.

Your options as I see are:

1. Require your users to have rooted devices, and do whatever linux does.
2. Run your own DNS server with records that have low TTL, so you can do a network call, get your stats, and wait for configured TTL before the next request. **This has a few caveats.**

   - Some domain registrars don't let you setup very small TTLs as this may overload their servers. Check before you buy. Azure and AWS provide managed DNS, ma be you can go with those.
   - Android OS or any other DNS server in the middle may decide not to respect TTLs to prevent them for being overloaded.
   - When connected to a home or more likely corporate WiFi, the infrastructure/[IDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrusion_detection_system) may flag the device as this can look very much like a [DNS rebinding attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_rebinding) from outside.
   - There is a bug on android making them not respect DNS TTLs on [versions below JellyBean](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36916773).

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of DNS caches under android

1. Java: 2s
2. Native: dns response TTL time [logics](http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/bionic/libc/dns/resolv/res_cache.c)

It's under the Interface and no exposed, So there is no way I could force it to do the DNS query without cache things

PS: if you have root you could clear with [ndc commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32442365/root-shell-command-to-clear-dns-cache-in-lollipop)

PSPS:
**Since My Requirement is measuring latency, Finally I made my request with OKHttp and it's [DNS interface](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-dns/), With this interface, just get the DNS from SystemProperties and made a DNS query(UDP) by myself**